# Staying in Australia on an ETA for about 3+3 months

Tags: visas, australia

The official website states

> you are able to enter and leave Australia as many times as you need to during a 12 month period

and

> You can stay in Australia for a maximum of three months on each visit

I just want to make sure this works:
Stay for less than 3 months, then visit e.g. New Zealand or Japan for two weeks and then come back and stay for another 2-3 months. Does that work?

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking, **yes**, as the 3-month clock resets when you leave Australia.

**However**, it is important to remember ETAs are meant for temporary visitors.  If, because of your itinerary, the authorities suspect you are attempting to reside or work in Australia in breach of the conditions, they can revoke the ETA and deny you entry.  Therefore you should consider bringing evidence to show that you are a genuine temporary visitor in case you are questioned.